# What is the difference between /usr/include/linux and /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include?

Tags: path, linux-kernel, kernel

**Question:**
I want to work with Linux kernel headers. I am having trouble understanding include paths while working with such kernel headers when writing C code that includes such headers.

I am working with Ubuntu 20.04

What is the difference between the headers located at

- `/usr/include/linux`
- `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include`
- `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`

For example, when writing an eBPF C code for the [bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc) toolkit in visual studio code, there are include path errors (shown by IDE) unless I update `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`'s `includePath` to include the correct path, such as `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include`.

I believe the `-I` option with `gcc` also includes the path to the proper header files.

I want to understand the difference between these file locations and there relationship.

Comment: `/usr/include/linux` contains sanitized headers for use by user space (including the C library). Everything installed by the `linux-headers` packages is for building external kernel modules for a particular kernel.